# Set Local IP Addresses for Router as well as DSL Modem

Tags: networking, router, modem

I have a [TP-Link TD-8616 ADSL2+ Modem](https://www.tp-link.com/us/products/details/TD-8616.html) and a [GL-B1300 Router](https://www.gl-inet.com/products/gl-b1300/) running [openWrt 18.06.2](https://openwrt.org/).

Network Setup (topology):

```
ADSL Line > Modem > Router > local devices
```

They both have the default local IP address of `192.168.1.1` Both their local IP address can be changed, however the modem seems much easier to do. **To what local IP address do I set my modem to access the internet?**

Considerations:
1. Must be able to reach internet
2. Ideally, I’d be able to access the modems browser-based GUI on the provided local IP address via the router. Right now,  I had to directly, connect a laptop with Ethernet to the modem to access it. This obviously, shut down the internet for all other devices.

If this was answered before, please link to the thread. I did found similar topics but didn't understood the answers.

Comment: Can you provide a topology of your network?  Edit your question to provide this vital information

Comment: One way of doing this is to change the modem (or router) LAN address to 10.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 - there are lots if other options though.

Comment: I just highlighted the topology which I originally named network setup. Sorry, I am not familiar with the terminology. Router is connected to Modem via Ethernet. Modem has only one Ethernet port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: removed the wrong suggestion that you could use 192.168.1.0/24 as intermediate network.

As an example, use   192.168.2.0/24 (192.168.2.0 with netmask 255.255.255.0) as intermediate network.
The network:

```
Inet    a+-------+ 192.168.2.1     192.168.2.100+------+192.168.1.1
---------| modem |------------------------------|router|--------------devices
         +-------+    intermediate network      +------+
```

In general, the home-routers have a DHCP-server. You can set your router to get the outside-IP address via DHCP. You don't have to, you can as easily put a fixed address on that interface.

Going from your device, you will have the router configured as default gateway. The router should function as NAT router (NAT Overload). The router will translate the devices address (192.168.1.xx) to 192.168.2.100 (in this example) and the return traffic will be translated back.  That means, that the modem will see traffic coming from 192.168.2.100, If the destination is somewhere on the Internet (151.101.65.69 for example), the modem will do a translation to the IP  address on the outside interface of the modem (just like the router did), to ip address "a" in our drawing. The way back from 151.101.65.69 will also be translated back.

This will happen more or less independent of the IP addresses that you use for your intermediate network.

However, if you want to access the web-interface of the modem,  you will access 192.168.2.1. The router does its translation, but the modem just handles the request. If you access 192,168.1.1, you will get access to your router; the traffic will not be translated.

So, if you would use 192.168.1.0/24 for the intermediate network, it would be impossible to get access to the modem, because the router will not do the translation, but handle the traffic itself. Also, the router would not understand on which side 192.168.1.0/24 lives.

Comment: This answer is either wrong or does not answer the question. If the LAN port on the modem is in the same subnet as the LAN port of the router the router will land up with the same netwirk for both interfaces and wont know how which interface to route traffic through. 192.168.2.x is not relevant ti the OP question unless they change an interfaces IP address.

Comment: 192.168.2.x __is__ relevant to the OP, because he explicitly ask for a suggestion " To what local IP address do I set my modem"

Comment: You might want to make an additional change to your post clarifying that to use 192.168.1 and 192.168.2.x the netmask should be 255.255.255.0 on all devices - I know you talked about /24, but many beginners wont know what that means, and many routers don't use that notation.  [ Which is also the reason my comment used the 10.0.0.0 range ].  Anyway, your answer is now correct, so I have upvoted it.

Comment: Setting my modem to 192.168.2.1 and leaving my router at 192.168.1.1 worked.I can’t access the modem through the router but that might be due to restrictions from the modem. I agree with @davidgo ,my devices uses the 255.255.255.0 system, but /24 I don’t understand.